# How to declare and store value in 2D array?

Tags: c#, c

I tried to print every pair of element while it's factorial
language: language-c

```
#include<studio library>//

in main function I try to store 2D array which size is
a[1][3];

And, I write these code

integer a[1][3] = {1,2,3,4,5};
and I find factorial of 5 = 120
I have to print three element together
it is possible 120 times;

so ,I can try 120 different value using print function function
in a[1][3];



like this output
1,2,3     is 1.
1,2,4     is 2.
1,2,5     is 3.
1,3,4     is 4.
1,3,5 up to 120
```

I want to know that how to store value in 2D array
but the array is a[1][3]

Comment: You never increase `j` or `k`. And when you do, how do you protect against them going out of bounds? I *assume* that's the problem you want to ask about, but you don't actually ask anything.

Comment: `printf` points that it is not a C#

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You may set the values of j and k to be "i-dependent" but they are not updating their value, you should add a j++,k++ next to the i++

Comment: not working
but not bed because you tried